# wordpress css file

Tags: css, html, ftp

i made a website by wordpress and i uploaded it to ftp file

> public html

my problem is that i made a css file that include all the other css files but when i tested the website i found that the wordpress didnt see the it saw only the first one what should i do to make the website see my files this is what is incuded in css file should i add 
url('wordpress/webcontent/....') or there is another way ??

> style.css

```
@import url('/styles/forms.css');
@import url('/styles/tables.css');
@import url('/styles/homepage.css');
@import url('/styles/reset.css');
@import url('/styles/stimenu.css');
@import url('/styles/layout.css');
@import url('/styles/demo.css');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use relative URLs to your imported css files. So try to remove first `/` from each import URL:

```
@import url('styles/forms.css');
@import url('styles/tables.css');
@import url('styles/homepage.css');
@import url('styles/reset.css');
@import url('styles/stimenu.css');
@import url('styles/layout.css');
@import url('styles/demo.css');
```

Also pay attention to the fact that using `@import` directives is bad practice and strongly not recommended to use. Use `link` instead of it. Why? Read here: [@import vs link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199364/import-vs-link/7199377#7199377).

So in your I strongly recommend you write your code like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse8170_enqueue_scripts' );
function wpse8170_enqueue_scripts() {
    $baseurl = get_template_directory_uri(); // if you write plugin use plugins_url();

    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse8170-forms', "{$baseurl}/styles/forms.css" );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse8170-tables', "{$baseurl}/styles/tables.css" );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse8170-homepage', "{$baseurl}/styles/homepage.css" );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse8170-reset', "{$baseurl}/styles/reset.css" );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse8170-stimenu', "{$baseurl}/styles/stimenu.css" );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse8170-layout', "{$baseurl}/styles/layout.css" );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse8170-demo', "{$baseurl}/styles/demo.css" );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse8170-style', "{$baseurl}/style.css", array( 'wpse8170-forms', 'wpse8170-tables', 'wpse8170-homepage', 'wpse8170-reset', 'wpse8170-stimenu', 'wpse8170-layout', 'wpse8170-demo' ) );
}
```

Comment: do you mean that i should add this function to function.php ??

Comment: @sarah yes i do

Comment: ok thanks but should i need to add something to the header to make it see this code ??

Answer (score 0):

Since your styles folder is in the same folder as your style.css file, the basic problem is the preceding `/` from the files' paths.

Use `@import url("styles/forms.css");` instead of `@import url("/styles/forms.css");`

This should sort out your problem.